# Loading data into a vector of structures

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I am trying to load some data from a text file into a vector of structures. My question is, how do you indicate the size of the vector? Or should I be using a the vector push_back function to do this dynamically, and if so, how does this work when populating a structure?

The full program is outlined below:

My structure is defined as

```
struct employee{
    string name;
    int id;
    double salary;
};
```

and the text file (data.txt) contains 11 entries in the following format:

```
Mike Tuff
1005 57889.9
```

where "Mike Tuff" is the name, "1005" is the id, and "57889.9" is the salary.

I am trying to load the data into a vector of structs using the following code:

```
#include "Employee.h" //employee structure defined in header file

using namespace std;

vector<employee>emps; //global vector 

// load data into a global vector of employees.
void loadData(string filename)
{
    int i = 0;
    ifstream fileIn;
    fileIn.open(filename.c_str());

    if( ! fileIn )  // if the bool value of fileIn is false
         cout << "The input file did not open.";

    while(fileIn)
    {
        fileIn >> emps[i].name >>emps[i].id >> emps[i].salary ;
        i++;
    }

    return;
}
```

When I execute this, I get an error that says: "Debug Assertion Failed! Expression: vector subscript out of range."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `vector` is expandable, but only through `push_back()`, `resize()` and a few other functions - if you use `emps[i]` and `i` is greater than or equal to the size of the `vector` (which is initially 0), the program will crash (if you're lucky) or produce weird results. If you know the desired size in advance, you can call e.g. `emps.resize(11)` or declare it as `vector<employee> emps(11);`. Otherwise, you should create a temporary `employee` in the loop, read into it, and pass it to `emps.push_back()`.

Comment: Oh my god, you're an angel! Got it to work perfectly with the following new while loop:  `while(fileIn)
 {
  employee temp;

  getline(fileIn, temp.name);
  fileIn >> temp.id;
  fileIn >> temp.salary;
  fileIn.ignore(1);

  emps.push_back(temp);

  i++;
 }`

Comment: you can also use `insert` to place your structs into a specified position whereas `push_back` always appends to the end of the vector.

Comment: @user633055: Glad to hear it; the code you show here is what I had in mind. If you are satisfied, you should mark your preferred answer as accepted; this will make it more likely that future questions from you will be answered. :-)

Comment: @AJG85: Indeed - but be cautious when using `insert()` to insert into large vectors (unless you always insert close to the end), as the performance of such operations is very bad (because all elements to the right of the insert position must be moved one slot to the right). (I assume you know this, @AJG85; this info is directed towards the OP.)

Comment: @Aasmund yes of course, I was just mentioning one of those "few other functions" worth knowing about :P

Comment: @AJG85: Can't argue with that. :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
std::istream & operator >> operator(std::istream & in, employee & e)
{
  return in >> e.name >> e.id >> e.salary; // double not make good monetary datatype.
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<employee> emp;
  std::copy(std::istream_iterator<employee>(std::cin), std::istream_iterator<employee>(), std::back_inserter(emp));
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, but the original code used an `ifstream`, not `cin`.