# need help with vector out of range error

Tags: c++

guys, I'm reading from a file and input into a vector, but I keep getting a pop up box with: "vector employees out of range!" error. It is like if I'm trying to access pass the last index in the vector, but if that's the case I don't see... any help appreciated
text file:

```
123 vazquez 60000
222 james 100000
333 jons 50000
444 page 40000
555 plant 40000
```

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct employees { int id; string lname; double salary; };
void getData(vector<employees>& list, ifstream& inf);
int i = 0;
int main()
{
    string filename("file2.txt");
    vector<employees> list;
    ifstream inf;
    inf.open(filename);

    getData(list, inf);
    inf.close();

    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++)
    {
        cout << list[j].id << " " << list[i].lname << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void getData(vector<employees>& list, ifstream& inf)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(inf)
    {
        inf >> list[i].id >> list[i].lname >> list[i].salary;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading data into a vector of structures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110306/loading-data-into-a-vector-of-structures)

Answer (score 2):

When you pass `list` into `getData()`, it has zero elements in it.  You then try to access the element at index `i` (starting at `0`), but there is no such element, hence the error.

You need to insert new elements into the container; the easiest way to do this would be to create a temporary object, read the data into that object, and then insert that object into the container.

```
employee e;
while (inf >> e.id >> e.lname >> e.salary)
    list.push_back(e);
```

Note that this also fixes your incorrect input loop.  In your incorrect loop, the stream could reach EOF or otherwise fail during one of the reads in the loop, but you don't detect that until after you've incremented `i`.

Comment: Notice that the vector is of type <employee>, which is a struct....I implemented your idea, but I'm getting errors: error C2039: 'id' : is not a member of 'std::vector<_Ty>'

Answer (score 2):

In your while loop in `getData`, you need to `push_back` an `employees` each time. Or you can define the `>> operator` for your `employees` class, and you wouldn't even need the `getData` function, you could just past an `istream_iterator` into the `vector` constructor.

Example using `istream_iterator`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

struct employee { int id; std::string lname; double salary; };
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, employee& e) {
  return is >> e.id >> e.lname >> e.salary;
}

int main() {
  std::string filename("file2.txt");
  std::ifstream inf;
  inf.open(filename); //add error checking here

  std::vector<employee> list((std::istream_iterator<employee>(inf)), std::istream_iterator<employee>());
  for (std::vector<employee>::iterator iter = list.begin(); iter != list.end(); ++iter) {
    std::cout << iter->id << " " << iter->lname << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`list[i].lname` should be `list[j].lname`