# C++ saving/loading a vector to a file

Tags: c++, vector, save

I am creating a Calendar application in C++.

Here is my code:

```
class appointment
{
public:
    appointment(string aDate, string aTime, string aType,
    string aLocation, string aComments, bool aIsImportant,
    string aReminderDate, string aReminderTime)
    {
        appDate = aDate;
        appTime = aTime;
        appType = aType;
        appLocation = aLocation;
        appComments = aComments;
        appIsImportant = aIsImportant;
        appReminderDate = aReminderDate;
        appReminderTime = aReminderTime;
    }
    void setDate(string aDate)
    {
        appDate = aDate;
    }
    void setTime(string aTime)
    {
        appTime = aTime;
    }
    void setType(string aType)
    {
        appType = aType;
    }
    void setLocation(string aLocation)
    {
        appLocation = aLocation;
            }
    void setComments(string aComments)
    {
        appComments = aComments;
    }
    void setIsImportant(bool aIsImportant)
    {
        appIsImportant = aIsImportant;
    }
    void setReminderDate(string aReminderDate)
    {
        appReminderDate = aReminderDate;
    }
    void setReminderTime(string aReminderTime)
    {
        appReminderTime = aReminderTime;
    }
    string getDate()
    {
        return appDate;
    }
    string getTime()
    {
        return appTime;
    }
    string getType()
    {
        return appType;
    }
    string getLocation()
    {
        return appLocation;
    }
    string getComments()
    {
        return appComments;
    }
    bool getIsImportant()
    {
        return appIsImportant;
    }
    string getReminderDate()
    {
        return appReminderDate;
    }
    string getReminderTime()
    {
        return appReminderTime;
    }
private:
    appointment();
    string appDate;
    string appTime;
    string appType;
    string appLocation;
    string appComments;
    bool appIsImportant;
    string appReminderDate;
    string appReminderTime;
    //person owner;
};

class calendar
{
public:
    calendar()
    {
        loadFromFile();
    }
    ~calendar()
    {
        saveToFile();
    }
    void createAppointment(string aDate, string aTime, string aType,
    string aLocation, string aComments, bool aIsImportant,
    string aReminderDate, string aReminderTime)
    {
        appointment newAppointment(string aDate, string aTime, string aType,
        string aLocation, string aComments, bool aIsImportant,
        string aReminderDate, string aReminderTime);
        //appointments.resize(appointments.size() + 1,newAppointment);
    }
private:
    vector<appointment> appointments;
    string calCurrentDate;
    string calCurrentTime;
    void loadFromFile()
    {
        //Code to load appointments from file
    }
    void saveToFile()
    {
        //Code to save appointments to file
    }
};
```

Can I please have some help with the following:

When the constructor is called, I want to load a file (loadFromFile() method) of appointment objects and set the 'appointments' variable to have the contents of this file.  After the saveToFile() method,I want to save the contents of the appointment vector to file.

Also, when the createAppointment() method is called, I want to increase the size of the vector by 1, and add the contents to the vector. I am not sure of the correct code.

**Update Saving/Loading from files**

```
    void loadFromFile()
    {
        ifstream iStream("file.ext", ios::binary);
        fileHeader_t fHeader;
        iStream.read((char*)&fHeader, sizeof(fileHeader_t));
        if (fHeader.magicNumber = 0xDEADBEAF)
        {
            appointments.resize(fHeader.appointmentCount); iStream.read((char*)&appointments[0], fHeader.appointmentCount * sizeof(appointment));
        }
    }
    void saveToFile()
    {
        ofstream oStream("file.ext", ios::binary);
        fileHeader_t fHeader;
        fHeader.magicNumber = 0xDEADBEAF;
        fHeader.appointmentCount = appointments.size();
        oStream.write((char*)&fHeader, sizeof(fileHeader_t));
        oStream.write((char*)&appointments[0], sizeof(appointment) * appointments.size());
    }
```

Comment: very similar to e.g. this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110306/loading-data-into-a-vector-of-structures

Answer (score 4):

Vectors are supposedly contiguous, so you shouldn't have any problem about loading them using ifstream, if I were you I'd create a basic header for your binary file with something like :

```
struct fileHeader_s
{
    DWORD magicNumber;
    size_t appointmentsCount;
}fileHeader_t;
```

Then, in a loop, just read each item in an appointment value, and use appointments.push_back( item );
You should do the same in createAppointment, don't resize the vector, just do push_back(newAppointment);

Comment: While there is no implementation that doesn't store it contigiously at the moment, it isn't actually defined in the spec, so it can't be relied upon. Also, saving with ifstream would require serializing the classes in question and serializing vectors, which isn't supported by standard.

Comment: @slugonamission If we're talking about `std::vector` then yes, it is guaranteed to store its elements contiguously **by standard**.

Comment: @slugonamission Since we are talking about `std::vector`: 23.3.6.1:1 (Class template vector overview) states: `The elements of a
vector are stored contiguously, meaning that if v is a vector<T, Allocator> where T is some type other
than bool, then it obeys the identity &v[n] == &v[0] + n for all 0 <= n < v.size().`. So it **is** defined that a vector **has to** store elements contiguously.

Comment: Most (if not all) of the implementations are using contiguous vectors, as it is specified by the STL : [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) "Just as regular arrays, vector containers have their elements stored in contiguous storage locations"

And about serialization, first he wouldn't use an ifstream that is made for input but an ofstream, and he could just : fStream.write((char*)&vector[0], sizeof(appointment) * vector.size());

Comment: For the appointments.push_back(newAppointment), I am getting the following errors: " E2064 Cannot initialize 'const appointment &' with 'appointment(string,string,string,string,string,bool,string,string)'
 E2342 Type mismatch in parameter '_Val' (wanted 'const appointment &', got 'appointment (*)(string,string,string,string,string,bool,string,string)')
"

Comment: Did you do this ? : 

    void createAppointment(string aDate, string aTime, string aType,
    string aLocation, string aComments, bool aIsImportant,
    string aReminderDate, string aReminderTime)
    {
        appointment newAppointment(string aDate, string aTime, string aType,
        string aLocation, string aComments, bool aIsImportant,
        string aReminderDate, string aReminderTime);
        appointments.push_back(newAppointment);
    }

Comment: Oh my bad, try this :
void createAppointment(string aDate, string aTime, string aType, string aLocation, string aComments, bool aIsImportant, string aReminderDate, string aReminderTime) 
{ 
appointment newAppointment(aDate, aTime, aType, aLocation, aComments, aIsImportant, aReminderDate, aReminderTime); appointments.push_back(newAppointment); 
}

Comment: Thanks. As stated in your answer, can you give me a quick example of how to save some test data to a file with a header and also how to easily read the data back in?

Comment: Yes of course, to save data here's what you could do :
ofstream oStream("file.ext", ios::binary);
fileHeader_t fHeader;
fHeader.magicNumber = 0xDEADBEEF; //put anything here, it's your file signature, make sure it's always the same for every file you read/save
fHeader.appointmentCount = appointments.size();
oStream.write((char*)&fHeader, sizeof(fileHeader_t));
oStream.write((char*)&appointments[0], sizeof(appointment) * appointments.size());

And to read it :
ifstream iStream("file.ext", ios::binary);
fileHeader_t fHeader;
iStream.read((char*)&fHeader, sizeof(fileHeader_t));

Comment: Then, from what you've read, just check if the magic number is equal to 0xDEADBEEF, and to finish just : 
appointments.resize(fHeader.appointmentCount);
iStream.read((char*)&appointments[0], fHeader.appointmentCount * sizeof(appointment));

Comment: I am having a bit of trouble with the loading and saving. I have edited my main post. Can you please have a look at it if possible and give me some help. Thanks.

Comment: DWORD is basically an unsigned long, either hard-type it or typedef it, and you do not have anything to modify about the loading/saving code, just remove the loop, the read instruction cares about filling the whole vector

Comment: OK. Now I just have 2 these errors: E2379 Statement missing ;
E2451 Undefined symbol 'fHeader'. This occurs at the line: fileHeader_t fHeader; in both the save and the load.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to come up with your own file format (i.e. save each record on a line manually), or use something like [Boost::serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html).

Comment: In your opinion, what would be easiest?

Comment: In this case, boost::serialization, since you're working with a vector of classes, or else you'd have to implement a custom way to serialize/deserialize your class.